# Beveled model has a bad sculpt remesh

Tags: edges, bevel, remesh, sculpt-mode

I need to sculpt model with beveled edges. But after sculpt remesh, it looks different. I have tried almost everything I know on it: applied all transforms, changed bevel settings and topology, checked for double vertices but nothing works for me.

Before remesh
[image: before remesh]

[image]

After remesh
[image: After]

[image]

Comment: Hello, I guess Remesh gives unexpected result, why do you want to remesh it?

Comment: @moonboots hello I am creating detailed model for game engine. There will be slashes, cracks etc.

Comment: I may be wrong but I wonder if remesh is not mostly use to simplify rather than to add density, maybe you should use Dyntopo to create your details? Also you could subdivide, but your topology is not homogeneous enough

Comment: @moonboots dyntopo looks the same way :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a simpler way but you could prepare your topology this way: First create the tip:

[image]

Then create some vertical loopcuts:

[image]

Bevel the angles that you want to keep sharp:

[image]

Aplly a *Subdivision Surface* modifier to add topology:

[image]

Sculpt:

[image]

Comment: I wish there will be another solution, but at least this is works and I can progress further. Thank you, my savior!

Comment: there may be another solution but I've tried several remesh solutions and I haven't found any good one  :((